# JavaScript for loop string to array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

It just all of a suddenly crossed my mind we all know using regular `for` loop and `push()` method to convert string **characters** into an array

```js
let myStr = "Perseverance";
let emptyArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myStr.length; i++) {
    emptyArr.push(myStr[i]);
}
console.log(emptyArr);
```

then I decided to convert **a whole string** into a single element of an array just using `push()`...worked

```js
let myStr = "Perseverance powers";
let emptyArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myStr.split().length; i++) {
  emptyArr.push(myStr);
}
console.log(emptyArr);
```

Now here when I want to separate **each word** into a single element of an array just using `push()` I can't...
Here is my question: **How can I convert each word of  the string into a single element of an array using only `push()` and `for` loop**

P.S. A lot ways exist yet it was just a thought came to my mind 'what if'
Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Please add more details.

Comment: edited my post by providing a question

Comment: That second example is odd. Why not just do `let emptyArr = [mySstr]`? Saves on the loop.

Comment: string being converted to array

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's `split` to create an array of words.

```js
const myStr = "Perseverance powers";
const arr = myStr.split(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

documentation for [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Here's what I came up with if you want to do this using `push`

```js
const str = 'Perseverance powers';
const arr = [];
let temp = '';

str.split('').forEach(character => {
    if(character === ' ') {
    arr.push(temp);
    temp = '';
  } else {
    temp += character;
  }
})
arr.push(temp);

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Indeed we can Thanks ... again it was just a thought and me trying to do it using push() and for loop

Comment: Awesome approach despite not using regular for loop ... liked and upvoted for trying Thanks